# Need assistance with PorterStemmer in Python

Tags: python, nlp, porter-stemmer

I am running this code:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
word = 'gardening'
tokens = word_tokenize(word.lower())
stemmer = PorterStemmer() # write code here
stemmed = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens] # write your code here
print(stemmed)
```

I'm getting the output ['garden'] but how can I get the output without the brackets and quotes i.e., garden

I'm getting the output ['garden'] but how can I get the output without the brackets and quotes i.e., garden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use normal list indexing to get the result. For example:

```py
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

word = 'gardening'
tokens = word_tokenize(word.lower())
stemmer = PorterStemmer() # write code here
stemmed = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens] # write your code here

# Print the first item in the list
print(stemmed[0])
```

**Output**:

```
garden
```

Or, for longer lists, you could use a for loop to print out each value:

```py
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

word = 'gardening'
tokens = word_tokenize(word.lower())
stemmer = PorterStemmer() # write code here
stemmed = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens] # write your code here

for s in stemmed:
    print(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

word = 'gardening'
tokens = word_tokenize(word.lower())
stemmer = PorterStemmer() # write code here
stemmed = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens] # write your code here
for s in stemmed:
    print(s)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation rather than posting only code.